# Как задать атрибут элементу fieldset в Joomla 3.x?

Tags: php, joomla, simplexml

У `JForm` есть множество методов работы с полями и атрибутами полей.

Например для того чтобы задать атрибут полю можно воспользоваться таким методом.

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('ID_BREED', 'hint', '');
```

Или для того чтобы удалить на лету поле из формы.

```
$form->removeField('ID_COLOUR');
```

А вот как поменять атрибут у `fieldset` а не у поля в нем, как то не могу разобраться.
Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось если кому интересно.
Правда код не особо кошерный.

```
$xml = $form->getXml();
$xmlelement = array_shift($xml->xpath("//fieldset[@name='info']"));

if ($xmlelement instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
    $xmlelement->attributes()->label = "Информация о товаре";
}
```